# Change a variable within a URLSession callback

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I want to check if a file exists and then change the context of a variable.
If I'm working with playgrounds, it will work but coding in a viewport, nothing happens.
I check if the file named "nameoffile.xml" exist, using the statuscode, and then the var color need to change into "blue".
Below you will find my (not working) code.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://myurl/nameoffile.xml")!
var color = ""

func checkFile()
{
    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    req.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    req.timeoutInterval = 1.0
    var response: URLResponse?
    var task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        { if httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {
            self.kleur = "blue"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your example, you are assigning the `"blue"` to `kleur` attribute, while at the top of your code it is named `color`. Is it just an error that appeared while you were rewriting this to SO?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

From your example it isn't totally clear if the color and url are attributes of the class you are calling checkFile on. I'll assume they are, because it makes the most sense.

So if the colour you want to change is an attribute of `UIView.backgroundColor` and you want to see the change immediately, you need to change it on a main thread like this:

```
// Your view controller you are using for the task
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // The ui element you want to change the colour of
    // If you are using a storyboard you would have a @IBOutlet here
    let button = UIButton()

    func checkFile() {
        // I've noticed you aren't using the NSMutableURLRequest anywhere
        // Also I've cleaned up your code a bit, hope you don't mind
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                return
            }
            if httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // This line of code will change the color
                    self.button.backgroundColor = .blue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. If I haven't guessed your problem, feel free to change your question or leave a comment.

Comment: Hey hi I have used same kind of solution but I have different problem. It works fine but after 1-2 days but it doesn't seems to work. I have tried using swift in my project. This gives me same response for Last-Modified, Etag, each and everything. Please let me know if anything need to do at  my end.